# Warnings about non-finite and missing values in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to graph a jitter plot in ggplot 2 using the following data:

```
 str(sigAll)
'data.frame':   68 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Housing          : chr  "G" "G" "G" "G" ...
 $ L_R              : chr  "L" "L" "L" "L" ...
 $ AvgSignal_Cell   : num  4667 5626 6749 4302 8863 ...
 $ AvgSignal_Nucleus: num  5625 5786 8339 5042 10337 ...
 $ AvgSignal_Core   : num  5692 5793 8623 5327 10426 ...
 $ AvgSignal_Cytosol: num  4320 5592 6350 4024 8452 ...
 $ Nucleus.Cytosol  : num  1.3 1.03 1.31 1.25 1.22 ...
 $ Core.Cytosol     : num  1.32 1.04 1.36 1.32 1.23 ...

dput(sigAll)
structure(list(Housing = c("G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S"), L_R = c("L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R"), AvgSignal_Cell = c(4667.281, 5625.753, 6748.821, 4302.14, 
8862.542, 8160.903, 4259.365, 6377.276, 2938.33, 1786.079, 2460.968, 
3805.467, 842.556, 5842.61, 6317.317, 2958.439, 7583.484, 2419.217, 
3351.486, 3019.56, 3982.284, 1682.302, 9255.921, 12874.314, 16576.198, 
5510.09, 2998.26, 2774.713, 3355.004, 1675.935, 1500.067, 1670.437, 
4562.254, 1651.55, 2871.248, 8650.244, 4096.282, 7192.81, 3626.317, 
7710.997, 7431.251, 10368.304, 10826.879, 3764.766, 7838.579, 
5149.657, 2902.157, 2973.057, 2910.946, 7094.155, 3160.45, 2961.928, 
5500.054, 6647.882, 4751.33, 6479.251, 3686.799, 10779.512, 9025.341, 
6150.956, 13520.425, 15737.4, 3873.127, 1011.066, 7912.693, 5080.677, 
3904.62, 4254.379), AvgSignal_Nucleus = c(5625.141, 5786.035, 
8338.721, 5042.111, 10336.674, 9415.416, 5063.513, 9760.517, 
4788.829, 2954.273, 3842.475, 6055.95, 1220.196, 7078.282, 9107.593, 
3455.438, 9442.108, 3561.904, 4189.992, 3679.477, 6284.242, 2325.681, 
12962.09, 16377.974, 20492.558, 8121.249, 4383.026, 3807.964, 
4762.702, 1808.383, 1968.519, 2121.696, 6755.935, 2198.508, 4115.209, 
11265.273, 5473.159, 8443.648, 6097.271, 9733.861, 12522.993, 
15700.239, 16515.46, 5986.234, 12159.457, 8176.894, 3283.194, 
3492.403, 3137.489, 8413.343, 4462.952, 3861.525, 6434.457, 7817.007, 
5239.022, 7996.582, 5447.356, 15555.778, 13825.38, 9141.095, 
19610.233, 24360.992, 6298.853, 1238.698, 12955.28, 12165.838, 
6687.778, 6991.215), AvgSignal_Core = c(5692.25, 5792.771, 8623.383, 
5326.838, 10426.03, 9517.662, 5017.144, 10431.759, 5182.965, 
3116.777, 4057.239, 6128.226, 1340.218, 7435.23, 9966.102, 3463.128, 
9949.568, 3734.983, 4495.367, 3813.66, 7001.152, 2620.812, 12615.17, 
16477.508, 21659.024, 8968.277, 4414.965, 4228.678, 5170.928, 
1626.985, 2160.301, 2170.497, 7198.885, 2297.426, 4434.205, 11041.269, 
5784.755, 8731.084, 6817.087, 10503.798, 13382.872, 18375.274, 
19047.415, 6619.618, 12680.014, 8557.711, 3407.408, 3968.511, 
3365.749, 9215.487, 5154.857, 4027.49, 6965.535, 7958.982, 5520.883, 
8714.677, 5509.19, 15465.187, 14694.959, 10555.259, 21704.829, 
27703.9, 6900.982, 1393.699, 12525.917, 14220.159, 7528.12, 7623.628
), AvgSignal_Cytosol = c(4320.128891, 5592.078458, 6350.194016, 
4024.046497, 8451.66313, 7751.396911, 3967.33623, 4902.391423, 
2470.130066, 1559.809189, 2137.690955, 3107.175386, 730.7038645, 
5340.429154, 5423.427627, 2784.185337, 6811.135901, 2101.582727, 
2975.565426, 2771.926861, 3238.097981, 1431.378272, 8098.147857, 
11677.25738, 15417.85385, 4610.957827, 2568.489581, 2345.607938, 
3019.745528, 1650.489702, 1401.175298, 1562.673288, 4017.603441, 
1398.054773, 2509.051456, 7729.562357, 3623.594534, 6742.840759, 
2877.025366, 6897.560561, 5530.822618, 8205.730285, 8876.905341, 
2792.718965, 6914.588745, 4228.927716, 2697.020365, 2751.190596, 
2812.953107, 6501.408041, 2588.617343, 2609.72313, 4910.434048, 
6231.03498, 4523.210332, 5948.038797, 3357.947058, 9607.826019, 
7914.362968, 5169.172234, 11212.46146, 12736.74635, 3179.154857, 
944.1356091, 7339.871366, 3714.50587, 3075.477246, 3542.827603
), Nucleus.Cytosol = c(1.302077124, 1.03468416, 1.313144288, 
1.252995214, 1.223034312, 1.214673446, 1.276300446, 1.990970561, 
1.938695078, 1.893996408, 1.797488543, 1.949020975, 1.669891264, 
1.325414456, 1.679305713, 1.24109482, 1.386275085, 1.694867375, 
1.408133044, 1.327407679, 1.94072015, 1.624784339, 1.600624023, 
1.40255314, 1.329144653, 1.761293272, 1.706460494, 1.623444369, 
1.57718654, 1.095664516, 1.404905583, 1.357734861, 1.681583337, 
1.57254783, 1.640145319, 1.457427016, 1.510422579, 1.252238975, 
2.119296921, 1.411203412, 2.264218881, 1.913326231, 1.860497478, 
2.143514644, 1.758522083, 1.933562016, 1.217341197, 1.269415142, 
1.115371953, 1.294080136, 1.724067874, 1.479668458, 1.310364203, 
1.254527863, 1.158253014, 1.344406497, 1.622228077, 1.619073656, 
1.746872118, 1.768386617, 1.748967706, 1.912654247, 1.98129795, 
1.311991612, 1.765055456, 3.275223792, 2.17454966, 1.973343268
), Core.Cytosol = c(1.317611151, 1.035888721, 1.35797158, 1.323751603, 
1.233606906, 1.227864101, 1.264612755, 2.1278919, 2.098255906, 
1.998178381, 1.897953954, 1.972281973, 1.834146588, 1.392253279, 
1.837602101, 1.243856849, 1.460779545, 1.777223876, 1.510760597, 
1.375815522, 2.162118639, 1.830970926, 1.557784598, 1.411076888, 
1.404801486, 1.944992198, 1.718895429, 1.802806825, 1.712372103, 
0.985758953, 1.541777822, 1.388964038, 1.791835632, 1.643301854, 
1.767283405, 1.42844685, 1.596413436, 1.294867299, 2.369491447, 
1.522827949, 2.419689244, 2.239322201, 2.145726947, 2.370312975, 
1.833805953, 2.023612503, 1.263397208, 1.4424704, 1.196517991, 
1.417460178, 1.991355352, 1.543263327, 1.418517168, 1.277313003, 
1.220567384, 1.465134526, 1.640642305, 1.60964478, 1.856745648, 
2.041963108, 1.935777356, 2.175115939, 2.170697028, 1.476164003, 
1.706558109, 3.828277434, 2.447789204, 2.151848426)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-68L))
```

And the following code:

```
   #Core/Nucleus Stats
    mean_cor <- tapply(sigAll$Core.Cytosol, sigAll$Housing, mean)
    mean_cor

    se <- function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))

    se_cor <- tapply(sigAll$Core.Cytosol, sigAll$Housing, se)
    se_cor

plot.cor.cyt <- ggplot(sigAll, aes(Housing, Core.Cytosol, color = Housing)) +
  geom_bar(aes(color = Housing), stat = "summary") + geom_jitter(shape = 1, size = 3) +
  geom_errorbar(stat = "summary", ymin= mean_cor-se_cor, ymax=mean_cor+se_cor, 
                width=.2, color = "black", size = 1) + ylab(label = "GFP Signal Intensity") +
  scale_x_discrete(name=element_blank(), limits=c("GH","SH")) + labs(fill = "Housing") +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(face="bold"), aspect.ratio = 1,axis.text.x = 
          element_text(face="bold", size = 12), 
        axis.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("deepskyblue2", "darkorange"))

plot.cor.cyt
```

And I am coming across the following warning messages:

```
Warning messages:
1: Removed 68 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summary). 
2: Removed 68 rows containing non-finite values (stat_summary). 
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
5: Removed 68 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
6: Position guide is perpendicular to the intended axis. Did you mean to specify a different guide `position`?
```

The graph that is produced is blank:

[image]

I am unsure where in the ggplot() command the warnings are popping up and why no data is being displayed on the graph.

Comment: `ggplot` generally relies on data frames. The issue is probably that your `mean_cor` and `se_cor` values are not in a data frame. If you put them in a data frame, along with the corresponding `Housing` values, and give that data frame to the `geom_errorbar` layer, I think it will work.

Comment: If you need more help than that, please make your example reproducible by sharing some data with `dput()` so it can by copy/pasted.

Comment: Also not sure what `stat = "summary"` would mean for `geom_bar`... I think that's what's used for boxplots where you plot the quartiles, mean, median, etc. A bar just wants a single value.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the above without success. I have edited the post to include the data using `dput()`

Comment: I think I have used `geom_bar` and `stat = "summary"` before to generate bars showing the mean from a data set. It looks like there is another way to write it, by simply adding `fun = "mean"`, but it seems to produce the same graph in the latest version of ggplot2

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by removing `scale_x_discrete`, which I was trying to use to rename the groups on the x-axis, but it was not necessary. Any ideas why this was causing the warning?